# How to Find find number of tables and importing last table data to googlesheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, urlfetch

I have a situation, where I have dynamic HTML pages, and number of tables are varies according to data.
Now I am using the Google Sheets `IMPORTHTML` function to import the data, but every time I need to count number tables and input index.

I can use the below code to get tables count manually inside browser console log.

```
var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
   function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });
```

[image]

Please help me to get the last(or max) table index every time I input the html page url code.

```
function doGet() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743').getContentText();
  var table = getElementsByClassName(html, 'table')[0];

  var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
       (i++, x);
    console.log (i)
```

I need to have a simple Apps Script function to get the table index to print in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I need to have a simple appscript function to get the table index to print in googlesheet.`, I understood your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of tables in the HTML of your URL of `http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743` using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. When you put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743")`, the script is run and the number of tables is returned.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const res = [...html.matchAll(/<table/g)]; // or var res = [...html.matchAll(/<table.*>[\s\S\w]*?<\/table>/g)];
  return res.length;
}
```

- When your URL of `http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743` is used, `96` is returned.
- As another method, when `split` is used, the following sample script might be able to be also used.

  ```
  function SAMPLE(url) {
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().split("<table").length - 1;
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Hi Tanaike and Ruben,
Thanks for the code, it works like a champ, but for my example it is showing 10 tables less, However i have modified the code to add 10 to the length. 
Anyway thank you soo much for helping me.